# How to get YUV from Android GLSurfaceView?

Tags: android, android-camera, glsurfaceview

Is there any way to get YUV buffer from Android Camera with `GLSurfaceView` ? (Not from onPreviewFrame)

Comment: What's wrong with **onPreviewFrame()**?

Comment: First, I want to do the filter by OpenGL ES and get the yuv data with the filter effect. Then, the fps is not high. @AlexCohn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a YUV buffer from the Android Camera by using the Android Camera API.  There's no reason to get OpenGL ES involved if you just want a single frame.  Use [ImageReader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html) to avoid data copies.

OpenGL ES works with RGB, not YUV, so anything rendered by GLES has been color-space converted.  You can do the conversion back to YUV in a fragment shader if you like.

In any event, the SurfaceView classes are not intended as intermediates in a processing pipeline; they are display endpoints.  You can't get anything from them.  See the [arch doc](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html) for details.

Comment: I want to do the filter by OpenGL ES and get the yuv data with the filter effect.

Comment: GLES does all its work in RGB, so you will need to convert it back to YUV yourself. You *can* feed the RGB frames directly to MediaCodec through an input Surface (API 18+) if you want to encode them -- the system will take care of the color-space conversion for you in that case -- but if you want software access to the pixels you'll need to do the conversion yourself.

Comment: How to get the RGB? Thanks.

Comment: Extract the rendered image with `glReadPixels()`. Example here: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/EglSurfaceBase.java#L152 . If you want to be tricky, remember that RGBA_8888 has 8 bits per color channel... if you add the YUV conversion to the fragment shader, you can output (say) YUV_444 instead, keeping the bulk of the math on the GPU.

Comment: Got it. So i must use `glReadPixesl` to catch the rendered image. Is it possible to covent the RGB to NV21 by fragment shader. If there are some links about the fragment shader, that will be great.

Comment: There are many links about fragment shaders; I don't have one to recommend. An image-processing example can be found in Grafika (demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg ). The fragment shader sets (r,g,b,a) for the fragment at (x,y), so you can make it do whatever you like, but some things will be more straightforward than others.

Comment: fadden, you are so nice! Thanks for your great help. Upvote and accept.